# Antialiasing in the options of HTML <select> with opacity css in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select, opacity, antialiasing

I had to change the button color of an html select (combobox), but since it is not posible to add an image directly to the button of a select, what I did was setting an image behind the combobox, and then making the combobox transparent "filter:alpha(opacity=0);" in iexplore and "opacity:0;" in firefox.
This way, you do not see the select, instead, you see the image (what is like a select, but with other color, and since the select is on top of the image (greater z-index) when you click, you are clicking the select. And when it shows the options, yes, you can see them.

The problem is that I need it to work in Firefox, Chrome AND IEXPLORE.
There is no problem with Firefox and Chrome, but the text of the options in Iexplore, appears without the antialias it gets in the other browsers. All the text of the page is antialiased, so I need this to be also antialiased.

I have seen how to make it, but it works if the text is inside a div, a H1 but not if it is in the options of a select.
For example:
http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-to-make-cleartype-font-face-fonts-and-css-visual-filters-play-nicely-together/

But it does not work in a select :(

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember IE doesn't let you color the background on an `<option>` only on the entire `<select>`. The hack you describe requires a background color and chroma so maybe try setting them on the select element.

Alternatively there are javascript solutions that implement select using non-native elements. By avoiding the rendering of a native select you avoid triggering bugs that are unique to IE's implementation of form elements (which uses native system objects). There are too many implementations to list so just search for 'custom javascript dropdown'.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer!!
But I tried the chroma and background hack and did not work at all. With a div it did, but not with the dropdown (combo)
When I began this project I looked a lot but there was no javascript solution that had all I needed, this one was the easiest and I think the best. JQuery, prototype and other JS frameworks had nice ones, but they did not work exactly like the native one. Then I had to insert it into icefaces, and this is a big problem with non native ones.